# CallbackQueryHandler() not working

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to use CallbackQueryHandler() with my bot, but i can't make it  work for my case . The code of the bot that i tried is the same as this sample :

```
def start(bot, update):
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton("Option 3", callback_data='3')]]

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose:', reply_markup=reply_markup)

def button(bot, update):
    query = update.callback_query
    bot.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: %s" % query.data,
                          chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                          message_id=query.message.message_id)
def help(bot, update):
    update.message.reply_text("Use /start to test this bot.")

def error(bot, update, error):
    logging.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))

# Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
updater = Updater(TOKEN)
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help))
updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)
# Start the Bot
updater.start_polling()
# Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
# SIGTERM or SIGABRT
updater.idle()
```

Comment: Do you see anything in logs? Have you tried to add a fallback handler?

Comment: Any updates about logs?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you used this [inlinekeyboard.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/inlinekeyboard.py) example. It works good for me.

Probably you have some problem with TOKEN, internet connection or something else. Code is ok.

To be sure, please configure logging to `DEBUG` level, so you'll see more verbose logs:

```py
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `CallbackQueryHandler` implies using `query.answer()`, even if not is answered. Try like this:

```
def button(bot, update):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    bot.edit_message_text(text="Selected option: %s" % query.data,
                          chat_id=query.message.chat_id,
                          message_id=query.message.message_id)
```